Joining 2 Kafka stream topics with KSQL DB stream
I have the following 2 ksqldb streams that I'd like to join based on the invoiceNumber.
<outputing to a new topic the total combined of the 2 streams>
-- the InvoiceNumber is the primary key if we can call it that.
-- the messages are posted onto the topics, with a key based on the store.id
-- salesbasket
CREATE STREAM salesbasket (
        InvoiceNumber VARCHAR ,
        SaleDateTime VARCHAR,
        SaleTimestamp TIMESTAMP,
        TerminalPoint VARCHAR,
        Nett DOUBLE,
        Vat DOUBLE,
        Total DOUBLE,
        Store STRUCT<
            Id VARCHAR,
            Name VARCHAR>,
        Clerk STRUCT<
            Id VARCHAR,
            Name VARCHAR>,
        BasketItems ARRAY< STRUCT<id VARCHAR,
            Name VARCHAR,
            Brand VARCHAR,
            Catergory VARCHAR,
            Price DOUBLE,
            Quantity integer >>) 
WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='salesbasket',
        VALUE_FORMAT='JSON',
        PARTITIONS=1);
       
       
-- salespayments       
CREATE STREAM salespayments  (
          InvoiceNumber VARCHAR,
          FinTransactionID VARCHAR,
          PayDateTime VARCHAR,
          PayTimestamp TIMESTAMP,
          Paid DOUBLE )        
 WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='salespayments',
       VALUE_FORMAT='JSON',
       PARTITIONS=1);

Not Fully answering my own questions as all is not 100% yet, but got this working.
The stream name is created lower case,
The topic upper case.
the first column invoice is dropped from topic ????
CREATE STREAM salescompleted as  
select 
    b.InvoiceNumber InvNumber, 
    b.SaleDateTime,
    b.SaleTimestamp, 
    b.TerminalPoint,
    b.Nett,
    b.Vat,
    b.Total,
    b.store,
    b.clerk,
    b.BasketItems,
    p.FinTransactionID,
    p.PayDateTime,
    p.PayTimestamp,
    p.Paid
from 
    salespayments p INNER JOIN
    salesbaskets b
WITHIN 7 DAYS 
on b.InvoiceNumber = p.InvoiceNumber
emit changes;

